# Laravel Validating An Array in Update Method unique filter

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-9, laravel-formrequest

I am new to Laravel. I try to validate an array in Laravel 9.
for using a unique filter I have a problem.
at first, I try to use this way

```
$rules =  [
    '*.id' => 'integer|required',
    '*.key' => 'string|unique.settings|max:255|required',
    '*.value' => 'array|nullable|max:255',
];
```

For the Create method, this works, but for updating, the logic is wrong. I need to ignore the current field.

for the update, I try to use this way

```
private function update(): array
{
    foreach ($this->request->all() as $keys => $values) {
        // dd($values['id']);
        $rules[$keys .'.id' ] = 'integer|required';
        $rules[$keys .'.key'] = ['string|max:255|required', Rule::unique('settings', 'key')->ignore($values['id'])];
        $rules[$keys .'.value'] = 'array|nullable|max:255';
    }
    //  dd($rules);
    return $rules;
}
```

I got this error

> `BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateString|max does not exist. in file /Users/mortezashabani/code/accounting/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php on line 1534`

how can I validate an array in the update method in Laravel 9?

**PS**: without `Rule::unique('settings','key')->ignore($values['id'])]` all filter is works without any problem

Answer (score 0):

hello you can try this code in your function

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    'id' => 'required',
    'key' => 'string|unique.settings|max:255|required',
    'value' => 'array|nullable|max:255',
]);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't have access to the $request in my class  .. in code. Validating is in a class that extends of  FormRequest class.. something like this tutorial https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns-exampleexample.html

Comment: hello pedram shabani, this is a unique validation  public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:10',
            'slug' => $this->getSlugRules(),
        ];
    }

Comment: dear Kishan, I don't know what you mean!!!

Comment: Hi dear pedram , the part I did not understand is that  the variable types of your rules .
Are id , key and value all array ? 
I mean id is an array  , key is an array and so on ..

Comment: if it is possible dd your request() and add it to your question .